# CUDA. Shared Memory vs Constant

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I need a large amount of constant data, more than 6-8 KB, up to 16 KB. In the same time I don't use shared memory. And now I want to store this constant data in the shared memory. Is it a good idea? Any performance approximations? Does broadcasting work for shared memory as well as for constant?

Performance is critical for the application. And I think, I have only 8 KB constant memory cache on my Tesla C2075 (CUDA 2.0)

Comment: Why don't you just use constant memory ?

Comment: What is the access pattern for the constant data - do all threads access the same constant location at the same time ?

Comment: Constant memory can be up to 64KB on your machine.  The 8KB number you are referring to is a per-SM hw resource, not the amount that is actually mappable.  And as @PaulR points out, the access pattern will be a consideration.  Shared memory can work well with either a broadcast (each thread accessing the *same* memory location) or coalesced (each thread accessing contiguous/consecutive memory locations) memory access pattern.  Constant memory really only works well if each thread is accessing the same memory location at a given time.

Comment: Thanks for comments! I know about 64KB size, but what do you mean with "hw resource"? I thought, it's just a cache per SM, and if you use more than 8 KB of constant memory, it is very slow, wrong? And about access pattern, well, all the threads don't access the same locations, at minimum not always. Does it mean, that constant memory (and shared uncoalesced) will be slow and the best way for me is shared coalesced pattern?

Comment: If you have 1MB of CPU cache, does that mean you can only access 1MB of data?  You can access more than 1MB, but the effectiveness of the cache will depend on the access pattern.  For GPU constant memory, the *maximum* mappable space is 64KB.  There is 8KB of hardware cache (*per SM*) that will attempt to cache that space, depending on the access pattern.  Accessing more than 8KB may or may not be slow, depending on locality and re-use.  Conceptually no different than CPU cache.  If threads are accessing different locations (at a given point in the code), constant mem is not a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In compute capability 2.0, the same memory is used for L1 and shared memory. Partitioning between L1 and shared memory can be controlled with the `cudaFuncSetCacheConfig()` call. I would suggest setting L1 to the maximum possible (48K) with

```
cudaFuncSetCacheConfig(MyKernel, cudaFuncCachePreferL1);
```

Then, pull your constant data from global memory, and let L1 handle the caching. If you have multiple arrays that are const, you can direct the compiler to use the constant cache for some of them by using the `const` qualifier in the kernel argument list. That way, you can leverage both L1 and the constant cache to cache your constants.

Broadcasting works both for L1 and constant cache accesses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know about L1 settings, but how exactly should I pull the data, how can I be sure, that the data is always cached and what about access pattern (if different threads access different constants)?

Comment: The disadvantage with using L1 instead of shared memory is that you can't be sure that the constants are always cached. I think that NVIDIA has not disclosed what type of cache the L1 cache is, but that the consensus is that it's regular associative. So, other data that you read may push out the constants. The advantage is that you don't have to use extra instructions to manage the cache manually.

Comment: As for the access pattern, you just want to consider what happens when the 32 threads in a warp hits an instruction that performs a memory transaction. At that point, the GPU will schedule as many 128-byte transactions as are necessary for servicing all the threads. You want to make the number of required transactions as low as possible by keeping the values accessed at the same time by the threads in the warp as close together as possible. If multiple threads read the very same value, then broadcasting is automatically used for those.

Comment: Remember, unless your algorithm is memory bound, there's no benefit to having perfect access patterns or manually managing the cache. With a compute bound algorithm, you just need to keep memory access good enough that memory latency can be hidden by compute. Even in a memory bound algorithm, there may not be that much benefit in spending a lot of time refining the access patterns. The L1 and L2 caches really help a lot, and refining the access patterns was much more important for compute architectures < 2.0, that were much more restrictive and did not have L1 and L2 caches.

Comment: Given a problem set smaller than 16 KB you will get the best performance using L1. If you are not using shared increase the cache to 48 KB. Nsight Visual Studio Edition and the Visual Profiler can provide L1 cache statistics. If L1 miss rate is high then I would consider looking at constant cache before shared. Shared has the overhead that you have to reload the constant data for every block. L1 and constant cache will be loaded on demand.